# How to offset a pict2e picture horizontally?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, diagrams

One way or another I have chosen to use the `picture` environment (with the `pict2e` package) to create the figures in my document. Now I am to deal with the consequences, the main of which is the figures falling out of place every time I change the document's geometry.

I can easily rescale by adjusting `\unitlength` and add/remove vertical spacing but aligning the `picture` horizontally seems to be more difficult. Is there a better way of doing this than changing the left margin for the part containing the `picture`? (To be clear: I'm looking to avoid shifting elements within the `picture` itself!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `picture` environment is just like a big letter so you can centre it with `\centering` or move it 2cm to the right with `\hspace*{2cm}\begin{picture}` or any other way you would position a letter.

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you ever so much. And I actually looked through a few `picture` manuals and then implemented the local margin shift with `changepage`!

Comment: Thaaaaaaanks!!!